A characterisation of TDI for a single inequality

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $b\in \mathbb{Q}$. Prove that the inequality $a^T x \le b$ is TDI if and only if the entries of $a$ are relatively prime.

So according to the definitions we need to find a solution $y$ for the equation $ya = c$ for a vector $y \in \mathbb{Q}^n$  and arbitrary $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $yb$ is minimal and $y \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.
I can see that we may rewrite $\min_b \ yb$ and $ya = c$ as
$$\min_b \ y_1 b_1 + \ldots + y_nb_n$$
$$\text{s.t.} \quad y_1 a_1 + \ldots + y_na_n = c$$
for $y_1, \ldots, y_n \in \mathbb{Q}$, but I do not see how to use the assumption here. Could you please give me a hint?
Remark: I work with the following definition:

A rational system of inequalities $Ax \le b$ is totally dual integral (TDI) if, for all
integral $c$ the LP $\min\{yb : y \ge 0, yA = c\}$ is attained by an integral vector $y^\ast$ whenever the optimum exists and is finite.

